# Using "almost" in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, idioms, grammaticality-in-context, idiomatic-language

Which one of the following 2 sentences is grammatically/ idiomatically more correct:

- "She is **almost a real** fan of the jazz band."
- "She is **an almost real** fan of the jazz band"

Tnx!

Comment: With no other context, I'd normally understand ***an almost real friend*** as meaning *an **imaginary** friend [who in many respects acts / is treated like a real person].* An AI-powered chatbot, for example. Whereas *almost a real friend* would actually *be* a real person, who for some reason could never actually be your friend (perhaps with the implication that you and/or they would *like* to be "real friends").

Answer (score 2):

The *almost a real fan* version says that she isn't a real fan yet, but she's getting close to being one.

The *an almost real fan* version says that she is a fake fan, but she is a convincing fake.

Both are grammatical. Which is idiomatically 'correct' depends on what you want to express, but it's probably the first version.

Comment: The distinction in meaning would probably be made more clear if commonly accepted styling were used in the second sentence: *She is an almost-real fan of the jazz band.* The hyphenation clarifies the meaning of the phrase. (An *almost-real fan* as opposed to a *real fan*.) In the second sentence, *almost* is part of a noun phrase.

Answer (score 0):

> She is almost a real fan.

The first sentence means that she is close to being a real fan. Here "almost" modifies "is", showing that she is not quite a real fan. This is idiomatic and probably what you mean.

> She is an almost real fan.

The second sentence means that she is a fan who is close to being real. Here "almost" modifies "real" instead of "is", so the sentence states that she *is* a fan, specifically a fan who is not quite real. This is strange and probably not what you mean.

Comment: I disagree with *"almost" modifies "is"*. The difference is that in the first ("natural") version, ***almost***  modifies the complete noun phrase ***a real fan*** (where ***real*** is effectively an *intensifier*, as in ***She's really a fan***, carrying the sense of ***very much***). But in the more "unusual" second version, ***almost*** does indeed directly modify ***real*** - which as you say, forces the interpretation "close to being real" (rather than "close to being ***very much***").

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmmm. I disagree (but not very confidently). It seems to me that "almost" changes the degree to which she *is* the noun phase rather than modifying a noun phrase that she unequivocally is (if that makes sense). Compare to "She almost is a real fan." Do you think the meaning is the same with this change, and do you think "almost" performs an identical function?

Comment: On reflection, I realise that like you, I'm "not very confidently" taking a position here (so I just made a "non-edit" to your answer, just so I could retract my downvote). I can't deny that my default interpretations of, say, ***He almost was incapacitated*** and ***He was almost incapacitated*** would probably be very different - the first (somewhat "unusual") version might be used even if he never *actually* suffered any harm at all (he simply had a narrow escape), where the second would usually imply at least *some* damage (but not enough to completely incapacitate him).

Comment: @FumbleFingers cheers. I agree with the "incapacitated" case, but I can't sort out whether this is a grammatical effect or an understood convention. I'll leave the answer as it is for now.